# How is 0 used in conditional operator in C?

Tags: c, conditional-operator

Conditional operator in C is used like this:
`condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false`

What does 0 mean when it's used in the `value_if_false`?

I've seen some people using it like this, for example.

`a == b ? i++ : 0`

It seems like it does nothing. Does this work like `return 0` in other functions?

Comment: What was before that? This can be an assignment, for example
`int c = a == b ? i++ : 0` meaning c will be i (i will then get increased) if true, otherwise c will be 0.

Comment: Your correct. If `a == b` is true, then the result of the full expression is `i++` and if it's false (that is `a != b`) then the result is `0`. Note that the increment of`i` will *not* happen if the condition is false.

Comment: @Vucko that line itself is a complete statement. it is not the case of assignment.

Comment: If it is a complete statement, then `0` can be replaced by any other number without changing the outcome.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks. it's been a little bit confusing to understand what the `0` exactly means.

Comment: `if (a == b) i++;` is the sane way to write this, if it's used as a statement. Or even `i += (a==b);` if there's a reason to avoid branches.

Comment: @EugeneSh. thanks. you mean whether it is `0`, or `5`, or just any other number, they would all do the same thing?

Comment: @PaulHankin I guess so. I think the intention was to reduce the number of lines but I personally don't see that much advantage of doing that.

Comment: To view it from a technical point, `?=` is called the "*conditional operator*". The *conditional operator* is one of the group of *ternary operators*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C language, *ternary* is shorter version of if statement and it requires both statements, `if_true` and `if_false`. It would be like this (in fact it can have multiple statements for one case, separated with comma):

Short:

```
condition ? if_true : if_false;
```

Long:

```
if (condition) {
    if_true;
} else {
    if_false;
}
```

You can also assign the value if you put something infront of `condition`.
Short:

```
result = condition ? if_true : if_false;
```

Long:

```
if (condition) {
    result = if_true;
} else {
    result = if_false;
}
```

Now here is the trick. In C language, writing `0;` is a valid statement, so your ternary becomes in longer version same as code below:

```
if (a == b) {
    i++;
} else {
    0; /* This is valid C statement */
}
```

Or if you have assignment too, it would be:

```
if (a == b) {
    result = i++;
} else {
    result = 0;
}
```

You can also do this:

```
int a;
/* Code here ... */
condition ? a = 5: 0;
```

That is effectively the same as:

```
if (condition) {
    a = 5;
} else {
    /* DO not touch a */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why someone might want to write `a == b ? i++ : 0;` is that s/he probably wants to have an (Caution! You are now entering an opinion-based area) easier and faster alternative to `if (a == b) i++;` - although this is of course opinion-based and I personally not share the same opinion.

One thing I can think of as a "blocker" at the `if` statement is the requirement to write the parentheses `()` which can be omitted by using the conditional operator instead.

---

"*But why the `0`*?"

The C syntax requires a third operand for the conditional operator. Else if you would want to compile for example:

```
a == b ? i++;
```

you will get an error from the compiler:

> "*error: expected `':'` before `';'` token*"

Or respectively, doing so:

```
a == b ? i++ : ;
```

would raise:

> "*error: expected expression before `';'` token*"

So they use `0` as kind of "*syntax satisfier*" to be able to use the conditional operator as replacement for the `if` statement. You could use any other numeral value here as well, but `0` is the most readable value, which signifies that it has no use otherwise.

To showcase the use at an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int a, b, c = 4;
    a = 2;
    b = 2;

    a == b ? c++ : 0;

    printf("%d",c);
    return 0;
}
```

The output for `c` will be `5`, because `a == b`.

---

Note that `a == b ? i++ : 0` is different when used f.e. inside of an assignment like f.e.:

```
int c = a == b ? i++ : 0;
```

Here `c` is either getting assigned by `i` or `0`, dependent upon `a == b` is true or not. If `a == b` is true, `c` is assigned by `i`. If `a == b` is wrong, `c` is assigned by `0`.

---

Side Notes:

To view it from a technical point, `?=` is called the "*conditional operator*". The *conditional operator* is one of the group of *ternary operators*.

If you want to learn more about the conditional operator `?=`, look at ISO:IEC 9899:2018 (C18), §6.5.15 - "*Conditional operator*" for more information.

Comment: I don't think that ternary is faster than if. I mean, ternary is a shorthand for an if...

Comment: I would say it is not even opinion based but just wrong.. But that's my opinion :D

Answer (score 1):

The `?:` operator is a *ternary* operator, but it is not called "ternary" as some answers and/or comments here suggest. It just is the arity of the operator, just as `+` is a *binary* operator or as `&` is unary. If it has a name at all, it is called "Conditional Expression"-operator

It is not quite equivalent to if/else, because it is a conditional *value* (with the consequence, that both expressions must have the same type) in the first place, not a conditional execution. Of course, both types can be cast to make them equal.

In the case of what the OP does, a better option (if `if` shall not be used) is in my opinion:

```
a == b && i++;
```

which resembles a bit more logical what happens. But of course it is a matter of style.

Comment: Yes, It is called "*conditional operator*" fully official. The standard clearly states `?:` as "conditional operator" -> C18, §6.5.15 Conditional operator

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about `0` one could write

```
a == b ? i++ : 1
```

And it would behave the same way.

Only difference is when you assign the expression to say another variable:

```
int c = a == b ? i++ : 1;
// a == b -> c will be i++
// a != b -> c will be 1
```

However it's much cleaner to write

```
if (a == b) i++;
```

Comment: thanks. would it be the same for this one? `a == b ? c = 1 : 0` 1 will be assigned to c only if `a == b`. if not, it will do nothing.

Comment: @mjaything Yes, but that's a weird way of doing it.

Comment: Note that the ternary operator is an expression with a return value which can be used in more than just assignment. This could also be passed as function argument among others. For example: `some_function(a == b ? i++ : 0)`

Answer (score 0):

It helps to think of the ternary operator as a shorthand way or writing an if-else statement.

```
If(a == b){
    i++;
}else{
    //if assigned, return 0. Else do nothing. 
}
```